# Rsyslog to use hostname instead of leftmost FQDN label

Tags: ubuntu, hostname, rsyslog, domain

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 configuration in which `/etc/hostname` reads

```
projectname-environmentname
```

and `/etc/hosts` reads

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 environmentname.projectname.tld projectname-environmentname
```

This results in `hostname` reporting

```
projectname-environmentname
```

and `hostname --fqdn` reporting

```
environmentname.projectname.tld
```

as is intended.

Rsyslog, however uses the leftmost label of the FQDN as the source, which is problematic in a centralized logging setup, since `staging`, for example, is not very useful in determining the source of the message.

How can Rsyslog be configured to use the actual hostname set instead?

Comment: Maybe this subject will cover your issue: [How do I get rsyslogd to log a server's FQDN instead of it's short hostname?](http://serverfault.com/questions/274625/how-do-i-get-rsyslogd-to-log-a-servers-fqdn-instead-of-its-short-hostname)